# gtsummary help repeated variable

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

[image]

```
df %>% 
    tbl_summary(by=Field)
```

It seems when there are repetitions in some variables, this package gives strange result. It has given me the n(%) of each variable instead of median(IQR) and p values. Is there a way to get around this?

I tried everything possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that by default `tbl_summary` uses the `categorical` summary type for numerics with less than 10 unique levels. From the docs `?tbl_summary`:

> ... numeric variables with fewer than 10 unique levels default to type categorical.

To fix that you have to explicitly set the type to be continuous:

> To change a numeric variable to continuous that defaulted to categorical, use type = list(varname ~ "continuous")

Using some fake example data:

```
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  Alphonso = sample(1:6, 100, replace = TRUE),
  Field = sample(c("field1", "field2"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=Field)
```

[image]

```
df %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=Field, type = list(Alphonso ~ "continuous"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have that on my radar!

Comment: @TarJae Yup. This is somewhat hidden in the docs.

Comment: Apologies, it was a decision I made a long time ago, and it's a continuing point of confusion. But it would break a lot of tables to change it now ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg No need to apologize. As a suggestion, to reduce the confusion you could add a reference to the "confusing" behavior at the beginning of the docs, e.g. to the description of `tbl_summary`.

Comment: I've had it documented in various places, and it didn't seem to make a difference. 99% of users don't reference the help file closely enough to identify there is an argument that defines the summary type.